# Nginx alias in document root not working

Tags: nginx, alias

If I give the following

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mywebsite.com;
    root /a/b/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /virtualLoc1 {
            root /a/b/c;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    #PHP file forward to PHP-FPM
            }
    }

    location /virtualLoc2/ {
            alias /a/b/c/d/e/;

            location ~ \.php(/|$) {
                       #PHP file forward to PHP-FPM
            }
    }
```

}

the http://mywebsite.com/virtualLoc2/ is not working where as http://mywebsite.com/virtualLoc1/ is working.

I'm using alias because I don't have virtual2 directory after /a/b/c/d/e/

but for virtualLoc1 there is a physical directory named virtualLoc1 after /a/b/d/c/virtualLoc1/.

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What can you read in `nginx-error.log`?

Comment: can you provide the path for virtualLoc2/ directory?

Comment: Error from Log

2015/07/20 14:35:19 [error] 6053#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.10.100, server: mywebsit.com, request: "GET /virtualLoc2/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "mywebsite.com"